# Finding k Number of Largest and Smallest Elements in an Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

Hi Stack Overflow community,

I'm working on a programming task where I need to find the k number of largest and smallest elements in an array. I've written a program in Java to solve this problem, but I'm facing some issues.

Here's my current approach:

```
package Arrays;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class KthSmallestAndLargestArray {
        static void printArray(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    static void KthSmallLargeArrayUsingLogic(int[] arr) {
        int temp=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                    arr[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sorted Array:");
        printArray(arr);
        System.out.println("Kth Smallest and Largest values using logic are:");
        System.out.println(arr[2]+" "+arr[arr.length-3]);
    }
    static int[] SmallestLargestArrayUsingFunction(int[] arr){
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int[] ans={arr[0],arr[arr.length-1]};
        System.out.println(arr[2]+" "+arr[arr.length-3]);
        return ans;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 5, 1, 8, 5, 9, 8, 0 };
        System.out.println("Orignal Array:");
        printArray(arr);
        KthSmallLargeArrayUsingLogic(arr);
        System.out.println("Kth Smallest and Largest values using function are:");
        SmallestLargestArrayUsingFunction(arr);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm encountering is whenever I try finding 3rd largest and smallest in an array{ 5, 1, 8, 5, 9, 8, 0 } it is giving me output as {5,8} which is incorrect it should provide output as {5,5}, However I try solving this by removing duplicates from an array and it worked but I don't want to remove duplicates.

Without removing duplicates:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUW7I.png)

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are wrong.  The sorted array is [ 0 1 5 5 8 8 9 ].  The third smallest is 5, the third largest is 8.

Comment: @TimRoberts: 8 is the third largest item/element, 5 is the third largest *value* - as Prabhjyot Singh isn't satisfied, *k smallest/largest element* may be worded misleadingly.

Comment: Good spotting.  If you are supposed to remove duplicates, then [5 5] is correct.  If you are not supposed to remove duplicates, then [5 8] is correct.

Comment: (See `println()`s, too.)

Comment: 1) if you would like to continue with the approach which you chosen: [sort the array,use the same array to find  the kth smallest value]: you iterate from the beginnig of array trying to find the kth unique value from the beginnig ( so you skip counting when the previous value is equal to the current).  2)Anyhow in this solution I would also recommend to use more efficient sort (the buildin java .sort() is perfectly fine).   3) You can solve this problem without sorting the array as well, but you would need 2 additional arrays of size k, if you want I can share also this solution.

Comment: Hey! It seems that you are new to StackOverflow. You can find many answers to this question on SO. Please check those before asking a question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You would at least have to make  a dynamic value, so that it not only works for 3 but for any any other valid .

One way to approach this is using two priority queues: one for keeping the  smallest (unique) values so far, and one for keeping the  greatest (unique) values so far. Also use a HashSet to skip processing values that were already encountered before.

At the end of this process, the two values at the fronts of both queues are the values to return.

Here is how that could look:

```
    static int[] SmallestLargestArrayUsingFunction(int[] arr, int k) {
        Queue<Integer> minHeap = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
        Queue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
        Set<Integer> collected = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (var value : arr) {
            if (collected.contains(value)) continue;
            collected.add(value);
            if (k > 0) {
                k--;
                minHeap.add(value);
                maxHeap.add(value);
            } else {
                if (value < maxHeap.peek()) {
                    maxHeap.poll(); // Make room for lesser value
                    maxHeap.add(value);
                }
                if (value > minHeap.peek()) {
                    minHeap.poll(); // Make room for greater value
                    minHeap.add(value);
                }
            }
        }
        int[] ans = {maxHeap.peek(), minHeap.peek()};
        return ans;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 5, 1, 8, 5, 9, 8, 0 };
        int k = 3;
        System.out.println("Orignal Array:");
        printArray(arr);
        System.out.println("Kth Smallest and Largest values using function are:");
        int[] result = SmallestLargestArrayUsingFunction(arr, k);
        System.out.println(result[0]+" "+result[1]); // 5 5 
    }
```